# Filter data from two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

Please help to make the request.

There are two tables, `artist` and `album`.
I want to select only those artists whose albums contains a picture. 
That is, if the actor has 10 albums and only one of them has a picture or does not contain, i want to skip (only if all albums artist has pictures)

**table artist:**

```
artist_id
---------|
1        |
2        |
```

**table albums:**

```
artist_id | album_id | picture_id
---------------------------------
1         | 122...   | true 
1         | 123...   | false
2         | 124...   | true
2         | 125...   | true
```

So, I want to select only artist where `artist_id=2` (because all the albums have pictures);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are a lot of solutions for this, the first that comes to my mind is a very simple sub-select to exclude the artists that have an album without an image:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  artist a
WHERE
  artist_id NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT artist_id FROM album WHERE picture_id = false);
```

**EDIT:**
if you have stored artists without albums, these have to be excluded, too (take a look at the comments for explanation). in that case, you'll have to add something like:

```
AND
  1 <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM album WHERE artist_id = a.artist_id)
```

Comment: just note that this will also return artists who have no albums at all

Comment: thanks for teh hint, i havn't thougth of that. i don't think it makes sense to store artists without albums, but if so, the query has to be changed to respect that.

Comment: you can add a simple join, but I agree it's probably unnecessary

Comment: @oezi: They may have only released singles, or may even have been recently signed to the company.

Comment: @oezi, thanks! Is there a way to implement without a subquery (just wondering)?

Comment: @thomas, yes, theres is - but i've chosen to use subselects as the logic for what exactly is done is more obvious (in my opinion)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `GROUP BY` clause to find the count of albums by artists. You can then compare this count with the *made-up* count. Aggregate functions can be used inside `HAVING` clause to eliminate groups:

```
SELECT artist_id
FROM albums
GROUP BY artist_id
HAVING COUNT(1) = COUNT(CASE WHEN picture_id THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

Complete example:

```
SELECT artist.artist_id, artist.name
FROM artist
INNER JOIN albums ON artist.artist_id = albums.artist_id
GROUP BY artist.artist_id, artist.name
HAVING COUNT(album_id) = COUNT(CASE WHEN picture_id THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

Comment: if artist 1 has one album with and one without a picture, it will be present in your resultset, but shouldn't, so this doesn't work as expected.

Comment: +1 - i'm sorry, you're right - i missunderstodd your query on first reading.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, without subselects, using the MIN() operator - if the minimum is TRUE, then all values are true:

```
SELECT artists.artist_id,MIN(picture_id)
FROM artists
INNER JOIN albums ON artists.artist_id = albums.artist_id
GROUP BY artists.artist_id
HAVING MIN(IFNULL(picture_id, 0)) > 0
```

EDIT

Modified the query to substitute the null values with 0 at the MIN() opertor, it's cleaner this way.

Comment: i dont know, im just asking.. What happens 1. if picture_id has NULL or 2. picture_id has ''(Empty String)?

Comment: It handles it correctly. However, we don't know the type of the "picture_id" column. If it's INT, it can't contain empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT  table1.id, table2.id, table2.name 
FROM table1, table2 WHERE id=id GROUP BY name");
```

Try this. Sure it works. 
Cheers !!!